Why is numpy fill_diagonal not changing dataframe values
I'm trying to use numpy.fill_diagonal() as shown in this answer to change the diagonal entries of my dataframe to be 20,000.  However, when I run the example below, the diagonal entries in my dataframe stay zero. My question is "Why?"
Please don't post some answer showing how to change the diagonal entries with a for loop.  I can change the diagonal entries myself.  My question is why the below example does not work to change the entries. If I don't understand why the below example fails, I cannot rely on numpy.fill_diagonal() in any of my code.  I'm using numpy version 2.1.0 and pandas version 2.2.2.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nodes = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
df_cap = pd.DataFrame(None, index=nodes, columns=nodes)

edges = {
    ('A', 'B'): 809, ('A', 'C'): 184, ('A', 'D'): 440, ('B', 'C'): 134, 
    ('B', 'E'): 277, ('B', 'F'): 138, ('C', 'D'): 194, ('C', 'F'): 144,
    ('C', 'G'): 139, ('D', 'E'): 190, ('D', 'G'): 284, ('E', 'F'): 100,
    ('E', 'H'): 281,('F', 'H'): 922,('G', 'F'): 123,('G', 'H'): 232
}

for i in nodes:
    for j in nodes:
        if (i,j) in edges:
            df_cap.loc[i,j] = edges[(i,j)]

nodes = nodes + ["Dummy"]


df_cap = df_cap.astype(float).fillna(0)
df_cap.loc["Dummy", :] = 0
df_cap.loc[:, "Dummy"] = 0
np.fill_diagonal(df_cap.values, 20000)

df_cap.loc["A", "Dummy"] = 20000
df_cap.loc["Dummy", "H"] = 20000
df_cap


The issue is that you initialized an object DataFrame and used a loop to fill your DataFrame, this created a fragmented DataFrame (i.e. not a monobloc underlying numpy array) and using df.values is making a copy (not a view).
A simple workaround could be to make a copy before np.fill_diagonal:
df_cap = df_cap.copy()

A better approach would be to avoid using a loop to create df_cap:
nodes = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

df_cap = (pd.Series(edges).unstack(fill_value=0)
            .reindex(index=nodes, columns=nodes, fill_value=0)
         )
np.fill_diagonal(df_cap.values, 20000)

And without fill_diagonal:
df_cap = (pd.Series(edges|{(k, k): 2000 for k in nodes})
            .unstack(fill_value=0)
            .reindex(index=nodes, columns=nodes, fill_value=0)
         )

Output:
       A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H
A  20000    809    184    440      0      0      0      0
B      0  20000    134      0    277    138      0      0
C      0      0  20000    194      0    144    139      0
D      0      0      0  20000    190      0    284      0
E      0      0      0      0  20000    100      0    281
F      0      0      0      0      0  20000      0    922
G      0      0      0      0      0    123  20000    232
H      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  20000


I haven't tried your second method yet, but when I add df_cap = df_cap.copy() before np.fill_diagonal, it still has zero on the diagonal.  Does it have 20000 on the diagonal for you?

Yes it does. Have you used anything other than numbers? This would make the dataframe not monobloc

I just used the exact code above, all in the same cell of a Jupyter notebook that has no other cells.  It has None (as shown in the post).

It works for me if I run df = df.copy() ; np.fill_diagonal(df_cap.values, 20000) right after the loop and before the Dummy thing. But, again, I'd avoid this method and rather use a non-loop method to produce the DataFrame. I added another approach to fully avoid np.fill_diagonal.

Hmmm, no matter where I put the df_cap = df_cap.copy(), or even if I do df_new = df_cap.copy(), it still has zero on the diagonal.

What if you first create df_cap with df_cap = pd.DataFrame(None, index=nodes, columns=nodes, dtype='float64') or df_cap = pd.DataFrame(0, index=nodes, columns=nodes)?

Also, note that your loops could be simplified to for k, v in edges.items(): df_cap.loc[k] = edges[k] (assuming edges doesn't contain nodes not in nodes).

I found that if I use np.fill_diagonal BEFORE I add the row/column for the "Dummy", then np.fill_diagonal works.  Otherwise, none of the things you've suggested work, not even your "better approach". So I can add the row/column after np.fill_diagonal, but then I need to change the ("Dummy", "Dummy") entry separately, which is why I was trying to use np.fill_diagonal after.  I think my takeaway from all of this is that np.fill_diagonal is fragile if used on df.values

Yes, this is what I mentioned in this comment ;)
